# Get Address of Last Executed Instruction in WinDBG

Tags: windbg

I'm reversing an win32 app.

Questions:

While debugging the prog. i found that the counter once jumps to address 0x0043D4A0. (This is a function entry point).

```
  0043D4A0   51               PUSH ECX
  0043D4A1   8B51 04          MOV EDX,DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+4]
  0043D4A4   8B4424 0C        MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+C]
  0043D4A8   3BC2             CMP EAX,EDX
  0043D4AA   890C24           MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],ECX
  0043D4AD   7D 06            JGE SHORT PEiD.0043D4B5
  0043D4AF   32C0             XOR AL,AL
  0043D4B1   59               POP ECX
```

Now I wanna know how can I get the Get the Address of previous instruction executed before jumping to this point 0x0043D4A0 using windbg. SO that I can trace from where this function is getting called.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a call instruction takes place, the return address is pushed onto the stack immediately before control is transferred to the called function.  The return address is the 4 bytes in the ESP register.  Run the dd command on @ESP, then run the ub command on the value at @ESP.  This will unassemble backwards from the return address, which will give you the sequence of instructions that took place immediately prior to and including the call.

Comment: Assuming that it's a CALL instruction used, the return address is pushed onto the stack and the target is jumped to. Thus, to see the return address in the debugger you would dump ESP, not ESP-4. Note that not all control flow changes are CALLs, thus the return address on the stack might not be the call site of the function. You see this frequently on the x64 as the compiler like to emply tail call optimization (i.e. replace, "return Foo()" with "jmp Foo" instead of "call Foo").

Comment: Thanks for that.  You're right.  I actually meant to say +4 anyway, but you're correct.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
? $previp
```

> The instruction pointer at the time of the previous event. (Breaking
>   into the debugger counts as an event.)

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for other psuedo registers

Comment: Actually i want to trace form where this function is getting called
So I put a BP @ 0043D4A0.
When debugger paused @ BP i entered "? $previp" n I got 0x7c810856

Evaluate expression: 2088831062 = 7c810856

So when i did this i found there is no call/jump to Address : 0043D4A0

0:001> u 7c810856
kernel32!BaseThreadStartThunk:
7c810856 33ed            xor     ebp,ebp
7c810858 53              push    ebx
7c810859 50              push    eax
7c81085a 6a00            push    0
7c81085c e973acffff      jmp     kernel32!BaseThreadStart (7c80b4d4)


What could be the possible reason for that?

Thanks,

Comment: $ea shows "The effective address of the last instruction that was executed. If this instruction does not have an effective address, the debugger displays "Bad register error".I'm getting Bad register error..:(

Comment: What does the disassembly window show or call stack window? If you see 'no prior address' in disassembly window you can manually try updating the offset a byte at a time until the disassembly window can generate the deeper call stack for previous instructions see http://analyze-v.com/?p=31 alternatively you could scan for that address using a script: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/debuggingtoolbox/archive/2007/07/20/windbg-script-disassembling-routines-and-searching-for-patterns.aspx