# Get last executed code statement after thread is aborted

Tags: c#, freeze, thread-abort

I have an infinite loop or something that takes too long to execute. I'm trying to know the cause of why this is happening.

I'm on Unity, and I'm looking at this code: https://github.com/synystro/LightOfHeaven/blob/master/Assets/Aevus/EmergencyExit/EmergencyExit.cs

The point is that when you press `Shift + Ctrl + Q` this injects a `Thread.Abort()` on the Unity main thread.

The question is, is there any code or tool that could allow me to know which code statement/operation was the last executed?

Maybe dotTrace?

Comment: Have you considered WinDbg? See e.g. [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990997/get-address-of-last-executed-instruction-in-windbg), [this cheat sheet](https://theartofdev.com/windbg-cheat-sheet/) or [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/getting-started-with-windbg).